# PHP exec vs execution of the same command in linux terminal

Tags: php, linux, csv, sed, exec

I have a very large file, 5GB csv file and I would like to display to user using PHP exec method.

I have tried to use the linux command to read certain line numbers (line 21 to 30) instead of all lines:

```
mycprogram largefile.csv | sed -n "21,30p;30q"
```

The terminal would return the exact number of line right after the command is entered. However, when I use similar command in php exec, it will wait for the first part (`mycprogram largefile.csv`) to fully loaded into the memory (which takes very long time) before going into `sed` to get the line number that I want. The php code is something like:

```
$cmd = "mycprogram largefile.csv | sed -n '21,30p;30q'";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Any idea that I could get what exactly I get from terminal with its output by using PHP method without waiting for the `mycprogram` to fully loaded?

Thanks
How

Comment: import it in to a db, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Does command `mycprogram` convert something line by line on `largefile.csv`? If it is the case, change to

```
$cmd = "sed -n '21,30p;30q' largefile.csv  > temp; mycprogram temp" ;
```

Comment: thx for your suggestion. But it has the same effect where the whole `largefile.csv` will still be processed by the processor (can see via `top` command). Nonetheless, I have added flags to `mycprogram` to get the number of line that I want instead of using `sed`. Lesson from this is that not all process or command behave the same when using PHP `exec` compared when you type the command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

use `-u` or `--unbuffered` option on sed to treat as stream flow, by default sed load all the file line by line forcing the whole previous input to be fully loaded/treated.